# how to read or extract graphical componenets such as square ,rect,line etc., from a pdf document using java?

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext, graphics2d, xml-generation

I am trying to extract all datas( such as square ,rect,line etc.,) from a pdf document which was generated using iText.But I'm not able extract the content rather than text and image.I want to extract graphical components mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be 3 options for this (at least those are the ones I could find), I do not know what you exactly have, so I will paste all the 3, these are in increasing levels of difficulty)

First Option: You could do something like so: (taken from [here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007917/how-to-extract-images-from-a-pdf-with-itext-in-the-correct-order)

```
PDDocument document = null; 
document = PDDocument.load(inFile); 
List pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
Iterator iter = pages.iterator(); 
while (iter.hasNext()) {
            PDPage page = (PDPage) iter.next();
            PDResources resources = page.getResources();
            Map pageImages = resources.getImages();
            if (pageImages != null) { 
                Iterator imageIter = pageImages.keySet().iterator();
                while (imageIter.hasNext()) {
                    String key = (String) imageIter.next();
                    PDXObjectImage image = (PDXObjectImage) pageImages.get(key);
                    image.write2OutputStream(/* some output stream */);
                }
            }
}
```

Second option could be to convert your PDF document to HTML, using something along the lines of what is shown [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/converting-pdf-html-using) and then, use [`JSoup`](http://jsoup.org/) to process the HTML and iterate over the `img` tags, which is how I am *assuming* that the images will be rendered.

Alternatively, you could take a look at the [`Hough Transform`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform):

> The Hough transform is a feature extraction technique used in image
>   analysis, computer vision, and digital image processing. The
>   purpose of the technique is to find imperfect instances of objects
>   within a certain class of shapes by a voting procedure.

An imaging library, such as [`OpenCV`](http://opencv.org/) should be able to yield such functionality out of the box ([`OpenCV-Java`](https://code.google.com/p/opencv-java/)) being a Java wrapper for such library.

[This](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/samples/HoughLines.java?r=02385ce192fb82f1668386e55ff71ed8d6f88ae3) example should point you in the right direction.

Comment: :I have drawn rectangle,circle,square and line in a pdf document using graphics libraries.so i wanted to extract the meta data of those drawings in order to generate XML document.